# When the nodejs application is running on localhost, how to integrate with api gateway aws?

Tags: node.js, aws-api-gateway

Application is perfectly running on localhost, can we directly us api gateway over it?

Comment: What you are trying? can you explain in more details?

Comment: i created a nodejs application which has endpoint(get,post). for this application i can use aws api-gateway directly?

Comment: Yes you can use EC2/Lambda of AWS service to host your API

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create one lambda function and link that lambda function with AWS API gateway.
after that, you will get endpoints for your APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can integrate your aws services from your localhost. AWS provide npm modules for integration of AWS serivecs. The **aws-sdk** npm module allwos you to access of AWS service such as **S3, SES, SNS, AWS Lemda, AWS Alexa, exc..** from varius platforms (**NodeJS, Java, php**).

**aws.js**

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const config = {
  region: process.env.AwsRegion,
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
  accessKeyId: process.env.AwsAccessKey,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AwsSecretAccessKey,
};
aws.config = config;

const awsUtils = {};

awsUtils.putObject = (file, key, encoding) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {
      Body: file,
      Bucket: process.env.AwsS3Bucket,
      Key: key,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      ContentType: file.type || file.mime,
      ContentDisposition: 'inline',
      ContentEncoding: encoding,
    };

    s3.putObject(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log(data);
        return resolve(key);
      }
    });

  });
};

module.exports = awsUtils;
```

I hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/create-api-using-awssdk.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway is used to access AWS Services externally (through an API as the name suggests).

This could be hooked up to a Lambda function or a Dynamo DB table. You would create endpoints in API gateway for both of these services.

API Gateway then generates an endpoint that can be accessed using NPM modules such as axios.

An Example Can Be Seen Below.

Create your API within API Gateway.

Now Create a Lambda Function with a language of your choice, and click triggers as shown below:

[image]

Now Add your lambda function to your API Gateway your created earlier, with settings as follows (note, you may have to deploy your API first to get a development stage(this is shown in picture 3):

[image]

Now navigate to your API gateway your created earlier, click on the endpoint your lambda function (your may need to refresh) and enable CORS with the following settings, as shown here:

[image]

Now Click the same actions tab, and click deploy API.

You will now have an endpoint that was created for you, along with an API key. This information can be seen at the bottom of your lambda function, as shown here.

[image]

And this function can be called in node using axios, or something similar in this fashion:

```
const header = {
    "x-api-key": "API_KEY",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

const body = {
    "exampleParam" : "exampleParam"
}

axios.post("URL_IN_LAMBDA_FUNCTION", body, {headers:header})
```